# Pandas Column/Index Values With Dollar Signs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook, dollar-sign

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['$0-$20','$20+']})
df
    A
0   0−20
1   $20+
```

How can I get the first value (0-20) to display with the dollar signs, as I originally specified? It actually displays the zero in a strange font and I'm not sure why it works for "$20+" but not "$0-"$20".

I've tried:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[str('$0-$20'),'$20+']})
```

...but no dice.

Here's specifically what I get:

[image]

I'm using the Jupyter notebook (Anaconda 3, Python 3.5)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jupyter, the `$0-$` gets interpreted as tagged latex.  It looks like you are running in iPython and something similar is probably happening.

[image]

Notice the odd font on the `0 -` and the bar after the `-`.  I know this bar is an artifact of a mathjax/chrome bug, which is what tipped me off.

You're dataframe is intact.  It's displaying it that's an issue.

Doing something like this should help:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['$0-$20','$20+']})
print df.__repr__()

        A
0  $0-$20
1    $20+
```

The `__repr__` method embodies how an object is to be displayed and returns a string.  Jupyter-notebook calls `_repr_html_` instead and passes it through an HTML handler.

Comment: Thanks. But how would I change the value in the data frame itself? I tried df=df.__repr__()

Comment: I've edited the post.  Your dataframe already contains the correct data.  It's iPython that is having trouble displaying it.  Type `df.iloc[0, 0]`

Comment: Okay, so ultimately, I'm trying to use the contents of column A in MatPlotLib as x-axis labels, but it's still displaying as such. Is there a way to escape the LaTex in MPL?

Comment: Good question.  I'm thinking about it.  That may be worth another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151646/pandas-to-matplotlib-with-dollar-signs