# Can't properly replace blank values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a python beginner, so I'm practicing some data analysis using pandas in a dataframe with a [list of restaurants with a Michelin star](https://www.kaggle.com/jackywang529/michelin-restaurants) (*`restaurants_df`*).

When I show, for example, the first 5 rows I notice that in the "`price`" column (`object type`) of row 4 I have a blank value:

```
In [ ]: restaurants_df.head()
Out[ ]:
    name            year    latitude    longitude     city        region    zipCode   cuisine           price
0   Kilian Stuba    2019    47.348580   10.17114   Kleinwalsertal Austria    87568  Creative              $
1   Pfefferschiff   2019    47.837870   13.07917    Hallwang      Austria    5300   Classic cuisine       $
2   Esszimmer       2019    47.806850   13.03409    Salzburg      Austria    5020   Creative              $
3   Carpe Diem      2019    47.800010   13.04006    Salzburg      Austria    5020   Market cuisine        $
4   Edvard          2019    48.216503   16.36852    Wien          Austria    1010   Modern cuisine
```

Then I check how many `NaN` values are in each column. In the case of the `price` column there are 151 values:

```
In [ ]: restaurants_df.isnull().sum()
Out[ ]: name           0
        year           0
        latitude       0
        longitude      0
        city           2
        region         0
        zipCode      149
        cuisine        0
        price        151
        dtype: int64
```

After, I replace those values with the string `"No Price"`, and confirm that all values have been replaced.

```
In [ ]: restaurants_df["price"].fillna("No Price", inplace = True)
        restaurants_df.isnull().sum()
Out[ ]: name           0
        year           0
        latitude       0
        longitude      0
        city           0
        region         0
        zipCode        0
        cuisine        0
        price          0
        dtype: int64
```

However, when I show the first 5 rows, the problem persists.

```
In [ ]: restaurants_df.head()
Out[ ]:
    name            year    latitude    longitude     city        region    zipCode   cuisine           price
0   Kilian Stuba    2019    47.348580   10.17114   Kleinwalsertal Austria    87568  Creative              $
1   Pfefferschiff   2019    47.837870   13.07917    Hallwang      Austria    5300   Classic cuisine       $
2   Esszimmer       2019    47.806850   13.03409    Salzburg      Austria    5020   Creative              $
3   Carpe Diem      2019    47.800010   13.04006    Salzburg      Austria    5020   Market cuisine        $
4   Edvard          2019    48.216503   16.36852    Wien          Austria    1010   Modern cuisine
```

Any idea why this is happening and how I can solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the code in your question, and not the screenshot. This would ease the answerer to reproduce your problem, instead of typing it manually.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm new here and I'm trying to figure out the best way to ask the questions. Thanks for the tip, I'll edit my post then!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing the dataset over at [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/jackywang529/michelin-restaurants#one-star-michelin-restaurants.csv) shows that the first four restaurants are 5 '$' while the fifth is 4 '$'. Thus, I'm guessing that jupyter notebook is just not displaying all the '$' visually, however the data internally is correct.

To double check if I'm correct try running

```
df.price
```

and see what you get. I think this might have something to do with jupyter's HTML handler when it tries to display four dollar signs. [You can look at this issue that is similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150927/pandas-column-index-values-with-dollar-signs)

If you're bothered by this, simplay replace the '$' symbols with a number using something like

```
df.replace({'price': {'$': 1, '$$': 2, '$$$': 3, '$$$$': 4, '$$$$$': 5}})
```

Comment: You're right! I just double checked and, in fact, Jupyther isn't showing the full content of the `price` column. I already had in mind to convert each set of symbols to a numerical scale, so I'll proceed with that analysis then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @ricardoper9 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hey, thank you once again for the tip. Sure, my problem is solved so I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you are dealing with both *blank values* and *null values*. These are handled differently. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159189/find-empty-or-nan-entry-in-pandas-dataframe) to understand how to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think pandas will recognize areas with '' as null.  for instance:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, ''], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

then:

```
df2.isnull()

    a   b   c
0   False   False   False
1   False   False   False
2   False   False   False
```

see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isnull.html?highlight=isnull#pandas.Series.isnull), and try:

```
pandas.options.mode.use_inf_as_na = True
```

EDIT:

you could also try replaying with:

```
df2.replace({'': 'No Price'}, inplace=True)
```

EDIT2: I believe @AKareem has the solution, but to expand you can use this to escape the latex

```
restaurants_df.replace({'price': {
                       '$': '\$', 
                       '$$': '\$$', 
                       '$$$': '\$$$', 
                       '$$$$': '\$$$$', 
                       '$$$$$': '\$$$$$'}}
           , inplace=True)
```